# How to change font-awesome in Moodle?

Tags: frontend, font-awesome, moodle

> I am using **Moodle** for the first time, I enabled email
>   self-registration as the user can signup.
>
> I need to change the required icon which is created as font-awesome
>   from **fa-exclamation-triangle** to **fa-asterisk**.

[image: Required icon]

Comment: [Later versions of moodle](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/8cf4c97217230e74e57e41f24e8afbbc8393eb79/lib/classes/output/icon_system_fontawesome.php#L57) use `fa-exclamation-circle` for required fields. If using v2 consider using v3 instead. If using v3, the icon is likely to be defined by your theme

Comment: @samthecodingman How can I change it from the theme?